# Next.JS Hydration Failure (The Initial UI Does Not Match What was Rendered on The Server)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I'm currently learning Material UI with Next.JS so, my source code is a bit messy. But to keep things short, I've developed the website for over 3 hours with no issue but when I decided that I want to move the source code to another folder and files (I'm using Next.JS 12 pages folder system) the error suddenly pops!

What's weird is that undoing all the changes didn't seems to make the error goes away.. so I think there must be something wrong with my code but I just cannot tell where it exactly is. Any help and explanation in that regards, is highly appreciated!

Side notes:

- I've checked the Next.JS web for my issue, it is said that invalid html (like putting div inside p) can cause the issue, but I'm not quite sure this caused mine because there are no case like this (or that I know of) inside my source code
- I've checked some previous issue alike in stackoverflow as well.. but because of my limited experience I'm still unable to pinpoint where exactly is my mistake
- There are no functionality yet on my website, I'm just trying to make the mock-up for some components that I want to use later

Below is my index.js source code for the page:

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import { 
  Grid, 
  Divider, 
  TextField,
  Button,
  Box,
  Card,
  CardActions,
  CardContent,
  Typography,
  FormGroup,
  FormControlLabel,
  Checkbox,
  Stack
} from '@mui/material';

export default function ToDoList() {
  const bull = (
    <Box
      component="span"
      sx={{ display: 'inline-block', mx: '2px', transform: 'scale(0.8)' }}
    >
      •
    </Box>
  );
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Quick To-Do List</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main>
        <Box
          component="form"
          sx={{
            '& .MuiTextField-root': { width: '50ch' },
            height: '80vh',
            width: '80vw'
          }}
          noValidate
          autoComplete="off"
        >
          <Card sx={{ minWidth: 275 }}>
            <CardContent>
              <Box
                component="form"
                sx={{
                  '& .MuiTextField-root': { width: '50ch' },
                  margin: '2rem'
                }}
                noValidate
                autoComplete="off"
              >
                <Grid container>
                  <Grid item xs>
                    <Stack spacing={1}>
                      <TextField
                        id="standard-name"
                        label="What Do You Want to Do?"
                        value="Buy LARGE Trash Bags"
                        InputProps={{endAdornment: <Button variant="contained">Submit</Button>}}
                      />
                      <FormGroup>
                        <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox defaultChecked />} label="Is It Done Yet?" />
                      </FormGroup>
                      <p>Your User ID is: <strong>eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9</strong></p>
                    </Stack>
                  </Grid>
                  <Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem>
                    Your Task Lists {'>'}
                  </Divider>
                  <Grid item xs>
                    <Box
                      sx={{
                        height: '30vh',
                        overflow: "hidden",
                        overflowY: "scroll"
                      }}
                    >
                      <Stack spacing={2}>
                        <Card sx={{ minWidth: 275 }}>
                          <CardContent>
                            <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 14 }} color="text.secondary" gutterBottom>
                              Word of the Day
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="h5" component="div">
                              be{bull}nev{bull}o{bull}lent
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography sx={{ mb: 1.5 }} color="text.secondary">
                              adjective
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="body2">
                              well meaning and kindly.
                              <br />
                              {'"a benevolent smile"'}
                            </Typography>
                          </CardContent>
                          <CardActions>
                            <FormGroup>
                              <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox defaultChecked />} label="The Job is Done!" />
                            </FormGroup>
                          </CardActions>
                        </Card>
                        <Card sx={{ minWidth: 275 }}>
                          <CardContent>
                            <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 14 }} color="text.secondary" gutterBottom>
                              Word of the Day
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="h5" component="div">
                              be{bull}nev{bull}o{bull}lent
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography sx={{ mb: 1.5 }} color="text.secondary">
                              adjective
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="body2">
                              well meaning and kindly.
                              <br />
                              {'"a benevolent smile"'}
                            </Typography>
                          </CardContent>
                          <CardActions>
                            <FormGroup>
                              <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox defaultChecked />} label="The Job is Done!" />
                            </FormGroup>
                          </CardActions>
                        </Card>
                        <Card sx={{ minWidth: 275 }}>
                          <CardContent>
                            <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 14 }} color="text.secondary" gutterBottom>
                              Word of the Day
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="h5" component="div">
                              be{bull}nev{bull}o{bull}lent
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography sx={{ mb: 1.5 }} color="text.secondary">
                              adjective
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="body2">
                              well meaning and kindly.
                              <br />
                              {'"a benevolent smile"'}
                            </Typography>
                          </CardContent>
                          <CardActions>
                            <FormGroup>
                              <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox defaultChecked />} label="The Job is Done!" />
                            </FormGroup>
                          </CardActions>
                        </Card>
                        <Card sx={{ minWidth: 275 }}>
                          <CardContent>
                            <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 14 }} color="text.secondary" gutterBottom>
                              Word of the Day
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="h5" component="div">
                              be{bull}nev{bull}o{bull}lent
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography sx={{ mb: 1.5 }} color="text.secondary">
                              adjective
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography variant="body2">
                              well meaning and kindly.
                              <br />
                              {'"a benevolent smile"'}
                            </Typography>
                          </CardContent>
                          <CardActions>
                            <FormGroup>
                              <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox defaultChecked />} label="The Job is Done!" />
                            </FormGroup>
                          </CardActions>
                        </Card>
                      </Stack>
                    </Box>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </Box>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Box>
      </main>
    </>
  )
}
```

===

Update:

Turns out my side note is wrong! I've put a Card inside a Box, which makes the error occurred! Putting the card outside the box fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Can you please show the error you're getting in browser console? This usually happens when there is invalid HTML.

Comment: I actually have resolved the issue and it actually because i put a card inside a box! I thought my answer got accepted but it suddenly got deleted by a mod! Haven't checked in a while so sorry to give this info late!